# Rails.root showing correct path but Rails.root.join is not showing correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Rails.root` work but `Rails.root.join` is not working as expected.

```
puts Rails.root # /work/project

src_dir = "/public/files" 
puts Rails.root.join(src_dir) 
# expected: /work/project/public/files
# showing: /public/files
```

Comment: It's `Rails.root.join('public', 'files')`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that with the first slash in `public` you're making a reference to the folder `public` located in `/`, not in the relative path where your project is.

Removing that first slash might give you the expected output:

```
Rails.root.join('public/files')
```